# Suspicious Linux binary file in /tmp/ - Munin?

Tags: linux, munin, csf, tmp

I have a CENTOS 6.6 x86_64 server running ConfigServer Firewall (installed by us) and Munin (installed by the datacentre).

CSF has recently (and for no apparent reason) started sending us warnings, at 5 minutes past the hour, about a suspicious file in /tmp/

Here's the file:

```
cd /tmp
ls -l
-rw-------  1 mailman   munin     477736 Nov  9 22:35 undo.#prelink#.XAy6Bg
```

I've tried to find out what this might be from the Munin docs, but am mystified.

Can anyone shed any light on the purpose of this file?

Should I remove it, or whilelist the file in CSF to prevent further errors?

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are prelink temp files and it is most likely due to selinux or some bug that was introduced with Centos 6.6 that those files aren't automatically removed. There is an old bug with similar behaviour https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=584550

They should be safe to remove but there will be other files with similar names so you might want to whitelist  /tmp/undo.#prelink#.XXXXXXXX